# Separate Listbox text without any characters - Winform (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wrote a code for my application.

**How it works:** The user paste in (*Let's say*) a list of IP on a `textbox` which is Separated by a character, and after button click the `textbox` text will send the list to the `Listbox`.

**Issue:** I want it to be separated without any characters.

I tried to separate them by line. However, it didn't really work out.

*Here is the code for it:*

```
List<string> lstIpAddress = new List<string>();
int nCount = 0;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string strIp = textBox1.Text;
        if (strIp.Length > 0)
        {
            lstIpAddress = strIp.Split(',').ToList();
            for (int nlstItem = 0; nlstItem < lstIpAddress.Count; nlstItem++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(lstIpAddress[nlstItem]);
            }
            label2.Text = listBox1.Items[nCount].ToString();
            nCount++;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Please try to describe better your problem. What happens and what do you expect to happen when this code runs?

Comment: So, what _"didn't really work out"_? Some comments on your code: You don't need `lstIpAddress`, you can just say `var addresses = strIp.Split(",");` and work with that array. A `foreach` is easier to type and read than a `for` loop. Do you really want `nCount` to count the times the button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a majority of this code.  Not sure if you really need nCount either.  Unless you need the list for something elsewhere you can remove that entirely and do this:

```
    int nCount = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(textBox1.Text.Split(','));
        label2.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();

        nCount++;
    }
```